# Why is the word "API" used in the Composition API in Vue 3?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have been reading about the new `Composition API` that is about to be introduced in Vue 3 which is set to release this year.

While I have been studying and exploring about the topic, I fail to understand why the word "API" is used. As far as I know, an API is used for sending/fetching data between the browser/app and a server.

Also, the Composition API is set to be an optional replacement for the already existing `Options API` in Vue 2. Even here, I do not understand the use of the word "API" in `Options API`.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Ask Evan the creator of Vue. https://twitter.com/youyuxi

Comment: API not limited to http and requests: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `API` is not restricted to interfacing with servers. In general, they are well defined layers that give you intuitive access to things that are more complex. You're constantly `interfacing` with things every day; imagine the steering wheel of a car being the `interface` to the front wheels.

The `API` is how you interact with Vue. It's an agreement for how your code interacts with the underlying logic in Vue. The team have introduced the `Composition API` because they believe it will help in creating cleaner, faster and more maintainable code.

The `Options API` is so called because you pass `options` in an `Object` when instantiating a Vue component. The `Composition API` is so called because you use `composition functions` to add functionality to a Vue component.